# Is this an implementation of a fixpoint combinator?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, combinators

I presumed this couldn't be called "fixed point recursion" because it was too straightforward.  However, I recently realized it actually might be.

Have I effectively implemented fixed point recursion?

Here's the function in question:

```
/* recursive kleisli fold */
var until = function(f) {
    return function(a) {
        return kleisli(f, until(f))(a);
    };
};
```

Here's some additional context:

```
// The error monad's bind
var bind_ = function(f, m) { return m.m === Success ? f(m.a) : m; };

var bind = function(f, m) {
    return m !== undefined && m.m !== undefined && m.a !== undefined ? bind_(f, m) : m;
};

var kleisli = function(f1, f2) { 
    return function(a) { 
        return bind(f2, f1(a)); 
    };
};
```

The rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/JimmyHoffa/Machinad/blob/master/machinad.js), but the snippet above should be enough to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of a fixed-point combinator is a function `F` which takes a function `f` and returns a function `p` such that

Given `F(f) = p` then `p = f(p)`

There are many possible fixed point combinators that could be written. Don't let the straightforwardness make you think that something isn't a fixed-point combinator; here is a standard definition in JavaScript, which is very simple:

```
  var fix = function(f) {
       return function(x) { 
        return f(fix(f))(x)
      }
  };
```

A usage might be then to compute the fixed-point for factorial, with:

```
var fact = function(f) { 
              return function(n) { return (n == 0) ? 1 : (n * f(n - 1)) } 
           };

alert(fix(fact)(7)); // alerts us with 5040.
```

For an example of a different fixed point combinator (the Y combinator) see [this helpful blog post](http://codehost.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/fixed-point-combinators-in-javascript/).

Let's see if your `until` combinator computes fixed-points. Since you are working with monadic functions the fixed-point definition changes slightly to handle the monadic structure, where `F` is a (monadic) fixed-point combinator when

Given `F(f) = p` then `p = f*  . p`

where `f* . p` means the Kleisli composition of the function `p` with the function `f` (in your code you would write this `kleisli(p, f)`, you can think of `*` as `bind`). I'll use this notation as it is shorter than writing JavaScript.

Let's unroll the definition of `until` then and see what we get:

```
until(f) = (until(f))* . f 
         = (until(f)* . f)* . f 
         = ((... . f)* . f)* . f
         = ... . f* . f* . f     (associativity of bind for a monad: (g* . f)* = g* . f*)
         = p
```

Does `p = f* . p`?

```
... . f* . f* . f  =?=  f* . ... . f* . f* . f
```

Yes- I believe so. Although I don't think this is a useful fixed point. (I'm afraid I don't have a good argument for this yet- but I think this is basically a greatest-fixed point which will just diverge).

To me, it looks like the arguments to `kleisli` in `until` should have been swapped. That is, we wish to do the Kleisli equivalent of application in the `fix` example, so we need to pass the monadic result of the recursive call `until(f)` to `f`:

```
  var until = function(f) {
      return function(a) {
          return kleisli(until(f), f)(a);
      };
  };
```

Let's unroll this new definition of `until`:

```
until(f) = f* . until(f)
         = f* . (f* . until(f))
         = f* . f* . ...
         = p
```

Does `p = f* . p`? Yes it does:

```
f* . f* ... = f* . (f* . f* . ...)
```

since adding one more composition of f* onto an infinite chain of f* composition is the same function.

Using your `kleisli` function I had some problems with divergence (some evaluation is happening too soon so the computation runs until I run out of stack space). Instead, the following seems to work for me:

```
 var until = function(f) {
     return function(a) {
        return bind(f,until(f)(a));
    };
 };
```

For more on fixed-points for monadic code you might like to check out [the work of Erkök and Launchbury](http://sites.google.com/site/leventerkok/mfix.pdf).

Comment: p is used in the actual implementation; I was using it as a predicate to put the exit condition inside of the combinator rather than in the function that's being fixed. I removed it for clarity because my question is about the way I structured it regardless of that exit condition; though side note, if a fix point combinator has an exit condition is it still a fix point combinator?

Comment: also side note, the "error monad" in haskell is Either, not Maybe :P

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Oh sorry- I did not read your code very carefully. Hopefully what I have written is still applicable. I may remove the last part in that case, as it is slightly tangential.

Comment: Why would I want to use bind instead of kleisli? Is kleisli just redundant because it's already in a function at the point where I'm returning kleisli?

Comment: Removed P in my question now; it was pointless indeed I should have removed it when I removed the exit condition

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I was having problems getting a result out without it diverging with `kleisli`. Did you not have this problem? (I was using a modified version of your code so I could be working against myself here).

Comment: I don't think I understand your meaning of 'divergence' here, it does work if you take a look on github at my actual code and use that (again, the exit condition is in the until combinator in the actual code I used)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa by diverge I mean "run forever with no result" (running out of stack space usually happens first). It's possible that your guarding condition `p` stops this. Hang on, I will change my answer to be more helpful. Sorry.

Comment: Hopefully this new edit gives you some more tools to work with to answer the question about `p`.

Comment: I have to run now. I will checkout your github code later and have a play.

Comment: Yeah that extra snippet proves definitively, if the combinator has an exit case it is not a fix-point combinator

Comment: Indeed. Sorry I think I made a further error in the working, but I have fixed this now. I think `until` in the question is a fixed-point, but not one that is useful for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting in the work to pin this down and the great explanation that really helped me understand the formal fixed point definition! I know it's not easy code to work with so I appreciate it :)

Comment: Isn't your first definition equivalent to `var fix = function(f) { return f(fix(f)) }`?